# Is promoting posts on Reddit legit?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Let's assume that there a Stack Overflow question that has been already answered and it has many upvotes (e.g. 100 upvotes) on a simple solution (assume that this post was asked at 2008 in the developer community). Thus, if I want at the present day to write an answer to this post because I think that the post is too old and the solution that provides is not so robust in 2019. Hence, if I will come up with an answer that I consider as efficient alternatives/solutions/libraries to get a better approach for the given problem this will be considered as a good idea.

My problem now is that if, for example, I create a Reddit post and say "hello everyone, go to this Stack Overflow question and check my answer to the given problem and then try judge it, then only if you found my answer useful consider to upvoted it". Is this legit or not?

The reason that I want to do it because the post is too old my answer will be much better compared with that of the 2008 and with this way, I will help the community get informed with the latest news solutions or libraries to got better answers.

Yes, it looks like that I want to promote my answer to get more upvotes but first of all I want to help and give the opportunity to write something better and then let the people judge it first and only if they found it useful to upvote.

How bad is this or not? Should I do it or everyone will chase me?

Comment: I wouldn't request people to upvote your content, that is what makes it a shady thing to do. If people want to upvote they will choose to do so out of their own free will, no need for you to instruct anyone - they may also choose to downvote and you cannot stop them. Other than that... well you are free to do what allows you to sleep at night.

Comment: In simple, do what evenr you want outside Stackoverflow under their TOS.

Answer (score 15):

Outside of the SO network, you can do whatever you want. Unless you tell people to do something that is against the SO rules like creating sockpuppets to upvote your question, I see no problem.

There are even [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) that encourage sharing links to your questions/answers:

- [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer)
- [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster)
- [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist)

Answer (score -8):

That's up to Reddit, and the subreddit's rules, not StackOverflow